# Word for participating in solving a puzzle?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

Is there a word or short phrase for collaboratively solving a puzzle, or to describe the individual's role in that collaboration? Looking for something specific to solving something, ideally puzzles, rather than something broad like teamwork. Thanks!